# c++ sfml mp3 music player error

Tags: c++, audio, sfml

I'm trying to implement music to the game using mp3 music file player but it fails to load mp3(error1) file and every time I press "E" then it prints error(error2).

> error1: failed to open sound file "music.mp3" couldn't open stream
>
> error2: Failed to play audio stream: sound parameters have not been initialized call initialize first

**Code:**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML\Audio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

const int WIDTH = 800;
const int HEIGHT = 800;
const std::string TITLE = "Game 2000";

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT), TITLE);
    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);
    sf::CircleShape shape(400.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    sf::Clock clock;

    sf::Music music;

    if (!music.openFromFile("music.mp3"))
        std::cout << "cannot find music.mp3" << std::endl;


    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Time time = clock.getElapsedTime();
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape))
            window.close();
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::E))
            music.play();

        //std::cout << 1.0f / time.asSeconds() << std::endl;
        clock.restart().asSeconds();

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Directory:**

[image]

**Edit**

I tried different Formats like mp3 wav ogg,
no change.

Current files in directory:

[image]

Comment: Please tell me if i did something wrong?

Comment: As a side note, for longer tracks (which are typically larger as well), you might want to use `sf::Music`, which supports streaming audio rather than loading everything at once.

Comment: @Mario You are not looking code what i have currently. I'm using sf::Music

Comment: Ah! My mistake, sorry. Thought I read `sf::SoundBuffer`. Was another question then.

Comment: What SFML version are you using? libsndfile has been removed for a while now.

Comment: The latest one libsndfile was just for testing purposes. how do set this up: https://youtu.be/axIgxBQVBg0

Answer (score 1):

Error 2 is a follow up error, since loading doesn't fail properly (this is or was a bug inside SFML).

Your actual problem is the fact that SFML doesn't support MP3 files. Convert the file to a WAV or OGG and try again.

Comment: @MemesTV This is really weird. `openFromFile()` should return false if there's some issue with the stream (e.g. file not found). If it doesn't work with ogg/wav either, are you sure the working directory is the location of your executable?

Comment: @MemesTV The location of your executable and its dependencies isn't necessarily the same as your working directory. How do you start the program? Can you load the True Type font into a `sf::Font` or does that fail as well?

Comment: Fixing this problem will takes ages. i will delete this post